# Oracle Exist function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table `idm_track` it has 3 combination `dw_dealer_id`, `dw_program_id` and `dw_product_id` I want to join this table with another table and another table which is `ism_interaction` also have these three `dw_dealer_id`, `dw_program_id` and `dw_product_id`, I was trying to write SQL like this

```
   SELECT    
      dw_itrack_id   
   FROM
     idm_itrack
   WHERE
      dw_dealer_id, 
      dw_product_id, 
      dw_program_type_id exists ( select  
                                   dw_dealer_id, 
                                   dw_product_id, 
                                   dw_program_type_id
                                    FROM IDM_INTERACTION_DTL_AGG
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply join will do,

```
SELECT    
      a.dw_itrack_id   
   FROM
     idm_itrack a,IDM_INTERACTION_DTL_AGG b
   WHERE
      a.dw_dealer_id=b.dw_dealer_id and 
      a.dw_product_id=b.dw_product_id and
      a.dw_program_type_id=b.dw_program_type_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want this. This will join both tables on each field:

```
SELECT *
FROM idm_itrack t
LEFT JOIN IDM_INTERACTION_DTL_AGG i
  on t.dw_dealer_id = i.dw_dealer_id
  and t.dw_product_id = i.dw_program_id
  and t.dw_program_type_id = i.dw_program_type_id
```

If you need help learning `JOIN` syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

With the `LEFT JOIN` if you have records that are not in the `IDM_INTERACTION_DTL_AGG` then the matching records will return a `null` value.

If you want records that exist in both then you can use an `INNER JOIN` between the tables:

```
SELECT *
FROM idm_itrack t
INNER JOIN IDM_INTERACTION_DTL_AGG i
  on t.dw_dealer_id = i.dw_dealer_id
  and t.dw_product_id = i.dw_program_id
  and t.dw_program_type_id = i.dw_program_type_id
```

Comment: In your case, it will give un-matched records also from IDM_INTERACTION_DTL_AGG table right?

Comment: @Mari it will return a `null` on records not existing in the `IDM_INTERACTION_DTL_AGG` table

Comment: the OP wasn't looking for null rows in the result set according to the query posted.

Comment: @jalynn2 that is why I was not done with my answer and included additional details

Comment: yeah. What he wants is matching records from idm_itrack.. In this case simply inner join will do right?

Comment: @Mari I included both a `LEFT JOIN` and an `INNER JOIN` query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT    
    it.dw_itrack_id   
 FROM
   idm_itrack it INNER JOIN IDM_INTERACTION_DTL_AGG iida
 ON 
  it.dw_dealer_id = iida.dw_dealer_id AND
  it.dw_product_id =  iida.dw_product_id AND
  it.dw_program_type_id = iida.dw_program_type_id;
```

Comment: In my case right now all the tables are empty its completely new model, so i have to find Itrack id for AGG table based on combination of dealer, product and program, something lke qry below I wrote qry like that to get idm_track id ofr IDM_interaction_agg table

Comment: SELECT    
      dw_itrack_id   
   FROM
     idm_itrack itrack
   WHERE
     exists ( select  
                    dw_dealer_id, 
                    dw_product_id, 
                     dw_program_type_id
                                    FROM IDM_INTERACTION_DTL_AGG iagg
                                    where itrack.dw_dealer_id= iagg.dw_dealer_id
                                    and itrack.dw_product_id= iagg.dw_product_id
                                    and itrack.dw_program_type_id= iagg.dw_program_type_id)

Comment: The join returns the dw_track_id of rows in itrack whose 3 id columns also exist in the AGG table. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Then I think this join will work for you. The answer provided by Mari does the same thing, using a different syntax. Either one will work.

Comment: Perfect thanks Mari and Jalynn